# Scala - Vals and Defs - Decompiled

Tags: scala, decompiling

If, in Scala, this `val foo: Int = 0` gets decompiled to this:

```
private[this] val foo_: Int = 0
def foo: Int = foo_
```

Then how can `def`s evaluate each time they are called but `val`s are evaluated only once? Since the `val` is decompiled to a `def` anyway?

Comment: The value of the original `val foo` isn't really being 'evaluated' when `def foo` is called; rather, the pre-computed result is being returned, and that result was computed only once.  The behavior is a bit more obvious when the assigned value is more complex than a simple `Int`, as Dima's answer shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a `val`, there is a private variable ("val"), and a getter method ("def"). The variable is initialized with a value, which is computed once.

For a `def`, there is no variable to "cache" the value, so it it is computed every time.

```
 class Foo {
    val bar = { println("BAR"); "bar" }
 }
```

Is roughly equivalent to

```
 class Foo {
     private var bar_ = { println("BAR"); "bar" }
     def bar = bar_
 }
```

The block initializing `bar_` is only executed once, when the instance of the class is being created. So, something like

```
 val f = new Foo
 println("Created")
 f.bar
 f.bar
 f.bar
```

Will print out "BAR", then "Created", and nothing else.

But if you define `Foo` as

```
 class Foo {
    def bar = { println("BAR"); "bar" }
 }
```

Then the block is evaluated every time you access `bar`, and the code above, will *first* print "Created", and then "BAR" *three times*.